# Walmart API Error - Undeclared general entity "rsquo" at [row,col {unknown-source}]

Tags: php, walmart-api

While submitting POST request to the Walmart API. [Item Feed](https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#bulkCreateUpdateItems) is submitted completely and Feed Id is also generated.

But while checking details for that Feed ID using [Feed Status](https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#getAFeedItemsStatus), I'm getting below error.

**Undeclared general entity "rsquo"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ingestionError] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => DATA_ERROR
                    [code] => ERR_EXT_DATA_0801001
                    [field] => IB
                    [description] => Undeclared general entity "rsquo"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [14,49]
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue of description text.

’  = **R**ight **S**ingle **Quo**te

I have replaced ’ with `&rsquo;`

There were other issues like **hellip** (…)  for which i replaced with `&hellip;`.

Reference I have taken is as follows:

https://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html